# The directory is not writable by the Web process: /var/www/project/frontend/web/assets

Tags: yii2

Установил yii2 advanced, но приложение не запускается, а выдаёт от это:
The directory is not writable by the Web process: /var/www/project/frontend/web/assets,
хотя в процессе инициализации yii этой директории присваивались права
"chmod 0777 frontend/web/assets".

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день.
Перейдите в директорию frontend/web и выполните в консоли команду

```
sudo chown www-data:www-data assets
```